# cannot read property of null using state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I found below code make sense, it simply show the filename when user uploaded a file but I got error of cannot read property of undefined of filename? why? isn't I already set filename to null in the first place?

```
export default class fileUpload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        React.defaultProps = {
            filename: null
        }
    }

    handleOnChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({filename: e.target.files[0].name})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
                {this.state.filename && <span className="filename-placeholder">{this.state.filename}</span>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include this line, it will work:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};   //line
    React.defaultProps = {
        filename: null
    }
}
```

You need to define the `state` in constructor.

Few Suggestions:

**1.** `defaultProps` is used to set the default value of `props`, not the default value of `state` variable. `defaultProps` is not required here, because you are using the `state` variable. Check the example.

**2.** You define the class name as `fileUpload` (started with lowercase letter), instead of that use `FileUpload` (started with uppercase letter.)

Check the working example:

```js
class FileUpload extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           filename: null
        }
    }

    handleOnChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({filename: e.target.files[0].name})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
                {this.state.filename && <span className="filename-placeholder">{this.state.filename}</span>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FileUpload/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```